# Convergence of the series depending on x $\ a) \sum 3^{-n+(-1)^n}*x^n $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a couple of series:

$$\ a) \sum 3^{-n+(-1)^n}*x^n \\ b) \sum 3^{-n+(-1)^n}*x^{2n} \\ c)\sum 3^{-n}*x^{n^2} $$

and I have to estimate for which **x** they are convergent. How can I do that? What does it change the presence of (-1) in  the power? For example, can I use Cauchy criterion $\ ^n\sqrt {\frac{1}{3^n}*x^{n*n}}$? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What "Cauchy Criterion" is that, and what do you do with that expression? I suspect the "$n^{th}$ Root Test" may be what you after.

Answer (score 1):

For (a).

$\begin{array}\\
s_m(x)
&=\sum_{n=0}^m a^{-n+(-1)^n}x^n\\
\text{so}\\
s_{2m+1}(x)
&=\sum_{n=0}^{2m+1} a^{-n+(-1)^n}x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m} (a^{-2n+(-1)^{2n}}x^{2n}+a^{-(2n+1)+(-1)^{2n+1}}x^{2n+1})\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m} (a^{-2n+1}x^{2n}+a^{-(2n+1)-1}x^{2n+1})\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m} (a^{-2n+1}x^{2n}+a^{-2n-2}x^{2n+1})\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m} a^{-2n-2}x^{2n}(a^{3}+x^{3})\\
&=(a^{3}+x^{3})a^{-2}\sum_{n=0}^{m} a^{-2n}x^{2n}\\
&=(a^{3}+x^{3})a^{-2}\sum_{n=0}^{m} (a^{-2}x^{2})^n\\
&=(a^{3}+x^{3})a^{-2}\dfrac{1-(a^{-2}x^{2})^{m+1}}{1-(a^{-2}x^{2})}\\
\end{array}
$

and this converges to
$\dfrac{(a^{3}+x^{3})a^{-2}}{1-(a^{-2}x^{2})}
$ if
$|a^{-1}x| < 1
$.

Note that 
the next term is
$a^{-(2m+2)+(-1)^{2m+2}}x^{2m+2}
=a^{-(2m+1)}x^{2m+2}
=(a^{-1}x)^{2m+1}x
$
and this goes to zero if
$|a^{-1}x| < 1$
so this does not affect
the convergence.

For (b),
it is the same
except with
$x^2$ for $x$
so the condition is
$|a^{-1}x^2| < 1$.